# Java array loop method returns last value in array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm making a program to determine who has the fastest time in a marathon out of an array of times and one of corresponding names. In order to make them match up I return the index of the lowest time instead of the value of the index. When I return the value of the index instead of the index it returns the correct name and time, however, when returning the index it returns the last value in both arrays.

```
package Lec3;

public class Marathon 
{
    public static void main (String[] arguments) 
    {
        String[] names = 
        {
            "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex",
            "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda",
            "Aaron", "Kate"
        };

        int[] times = 
        {
            341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299,
            343, 317, 265
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + times[i]);
        }

        int key = firstPlace(times, names);

        System.out.println("In first place is " + names[key] + " with a time of " + times[key] + " minutes!");

    }

    public static int firstPlace(int[] time, String[] names)
    {
        int i;
        int bestTime = 1000;
        int firstValue = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < time.length; i++)
        {
            if(time[i] < bestTime)
            {
                firstValue = i; 
            }
        }
        return firstValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: better solution -> use hash

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = 0; i < time.length; i++)
{
    if(time[i] < bestTime)
    {
        firstValue = i; 
    }
}
```

In this loop you don't update `bestTime` so the times are all compared against the initial value of `1000`. They're all smaller leading to a victory for the last one.

Comment: Edit: I understand what you mean now in that I don't update bestTime and am only comparing it against the initial value. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have a loop in `main` where you iterate `names` to display all of the names and times. You can find the lowest `key` in that loop. Like,

```
int key = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + times[i]);
    if (times[i] < times[key]) {
        key = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("In first place is " + names[key] + " with a time of " + times[key] + " minutes!");
```

**Or**, in your current method, change

```
if(time[i] < bestTime)
```

to

```
if (time[i] < time[firstValue])
```

and eliminate `bestTime`.

Comment: @nox Get out a pencil and paper and write down what's happening every loop iteration: play computer.